# rotate one entry of an array

Tags: rotating, arrays

I have the following matrix and I want to rotate the entry in row 1 column 2 90 degrees so that it actually looks like a column.

```
\left[ \def\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
    &&&\\
    &[X_{n-1}, A_{n-1}]& & \lambda_n\mathbf{y}- A_{n-1}\mathbf{y}\\
    &&&\\\hline
    &\lambda_n\mathbf{y}^T-\mathbf{y}^TA_{n-1}& & 0
\end{array}
\right] \]
```

The output looks like this

[image: The original matrix]

I used the `\rotating` package and it does work, except the problem is with the vertical centering. The code now is:

```
\[ \left[ \def\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
    &&&\\
    &[X_{n-1}, A_{n-1}]& & \text{\begin{sideways}$\lambda_n\mathbf{y}- A_{n-1}\mathbf{y}$\end{sideways}}\\
    &&&\\\hline
    &\lambda_n\mathbf{y}^T-\mathbf{y}^TA_{n-1}& & 0
\end{array}
\right]\]
```

And the output looks like:

[image: The output after using the <code>rotating</code> package]

How can I adjust this so that the (1,1) entry is still centered? Or in other words, how can I define the anchor of rotation for the (1,2) entry? I know tikz would do this easily, but I'm trying to avoid tikz if this can be done using simple commands in Latex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use `\rotatebox`, of course assuming you *really* want to rotate the thing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\[
\left[
\begin{array}{c|c}
  \\ \relax
  [X_{n-1}, A_{n-1}] & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\lambda_n\mathbf{y}- A_{n-1}\mathbf{y}$}\\
  \\
  \hline
  \\[-1ex]
  \lambda_n\mathbf{y}^T-\mathbf{y}^TA_{n-1}& 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I used the `\rotcell` command from `makecell`, with some adjustments:

```
 \documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{rotating, makecell}

\begin{document}

\[\setlength\rotheadsize{24pt}\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}\left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|c}
        & & & \\
        & [X_{n-1}, A_{n-1}] & & \rotcell{\makebox[24pt]{$ \lambda_n\mathbf{y}- A_{n-1}\mathbf{y} $}} \\
        & & & \\
      \hline\
        & \lambda_n\mathbf{y}^T-\mathbf{y}^TA_{n-1} & & 0
    \end{array}
  \right] \]

\end{document}
```

[image]